# error on adding location package in flutter, can I perform required functionality without using location package

Tags: flutter, firebase, location

On adding location package in flutter project I have following error

Launching lib\main.dart on RMX3195 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':location' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: i want to take current location of user in Google Map API

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your application, if not then try the following commands on terminal to do so.
```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```
I hope this would help you out

Comment: i have tried this , bu same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue, then I updated 'ext.kotlin_version' in android/build.gradle to latest version. In my condition I'm using 1.9.10 version. Then I restart my IDE, and execute 'flutter run' in terminal.
It works for me.